# Reinstalling immudb database

Tags: linux, database, go

I’ve been using immudb for an application and I’d like to clean it out and re-install and install again. Is it sufficient to just delete the immudb folder or is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, deleting the data folder would be fine and that will work. Also, you can use a separate data folder for a new instance, without deleting, by setting `dir` flag such as ./immudb --dir mydata